# Modelos con Django y Formularios

Tags: html, django, formularios, relaciones

buen día. Disculpen soy nueva con el Framework Django y quisiera pedirles de su ayuda.
Tengo tres modelos en los cuales dos estan relacionados, pero su relación es OneToOne. Al momento de realizar mi formulario utilizando un select manda a traer la info de lo que es el modelo relacionado, trayendo solo la información del primer campo, quisiera saber el como puedo utilizar los demás campos de la tabla que tiene relación OneToOne trayendome la info de todos los campos y no solo el primero que este caso sería "nombre del producto"...la info de la tabla de Calazado quiero que me lo muestre en el mismo html que el de pedido.... quizas en una tabla o atraves de otros select.  espero y me puedan ayudaa, además estaba leyendo algo sobre clases extendidas, no sé si sea algo así parecido?.

estos son mis modelos:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    clave = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numTel = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.username)

class Calzado(models.Model):
    tipoCalzado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    modeloCalzado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numCalzadoDisponible = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    colorCalzado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    calzadoExistente = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.tipoCalzado)


class Pedido(models.Model):
    nombreCliente = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fechaPedido = models.DateField()
    calzado = models.OneToOneField(Calzado, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    numCalzadoSolicitado = models.IntegerField()
    usuario = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario)
```

Comment: Saludos y bienvenida es mejor si agregas tu codigo, lo que has intentado tanto tus models como tus forms para poder darte una mejor respuesta..!!

Comment: listo, he actualizado compartiendo los modelos que tengo.. espero y puedas ayudarme...

Answer (score 0):

Como los modelos están relacionados, Django automáticamente usará la clave primaria del modelo para el VALUE del elemento SELECT HTML y para el display name o texto que se va a mostrar DJANGO utilizara el método (**str**) o ( **unicode**) del modelo en cuestión.

Entonces tu puedes tener el modelo:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  id=model....   #ESTE VALOR LO TOMA AUTOMATICAMENTE PARA EL VALUE DEL SELECT HTML
  name=model....
  description=model...
  category=model.....

  def __str__(self):
     return name + "-" +category.name";  #ESTE VALOR LO TOMA PARA EL DISPLAY NAME O TEXTO QUE VA MOSTRARSE EN EL SELECT HTML , AQUI PUEDES CONCATENAR LO QUE DESEES
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. La otra forma es renderizando el formulario manualmente

--@barckl3y--